# Can I use Carbon APIs to launch an application via jna?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macos-carbon, jna, core-foundation

In brief: is Carbon valid for this task, or should I dump it and look for a Cocoa solution?

Trying to write an applet which interrogates the client system (Snow Leopard and later) to list applications claim to be able to edit a single given file. User selects an application, and my applet then calls on Launch Services to launch the application, with the file as an argument.

I can get the list of eligible applications by calling LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL.
I can convert a file path to a FSRef object by calling FSPathMakeRef.
What I can't do is to construct and use a LSApplicationParameters object (one of whose members is a FSRef) in order to successfully call LSOPenURLsWithRole (one of whose arguments is a LSApplicationParameters).

What I done so far:

`interface MyCarbonWrapper extends com.sun.jna.Library

{

public static final MyCarbonWrapper INSTANCE =

  (MyCarbonWrapper) Native.loadLibrary("Carbon", MyCarbonWrapper.class);

// .. various function declarations, including

  com.sun.jna.Pointer LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(Object curlRef, int rolesMask);

  int FSPathMakeRef(Object path, PointerByReference ref, Void isDirectory);

  int LSOpenURLsWithRole(Pointer ptrArray, int roles, Void inAEParam,

    Structure myLSApplicationParams, Void outPsns, int inMaxPSCount);

}



// unsuccessful attempt to define a mapped LSApplicationParameters

public static class LSApplicationParameters

{

public int version;

public int flags;

public Pointer Application;

public Void asyncLaunchRefCon;

public Void environment;

public Void argv;

public Void initialEvent;

public static final int sizeof = 28;

}



public void openWith(String filePath)

{

  // create a CURLRef for the selected application - OK

  // Create a FSRef from the CURLRef - OK

  // Create a CFArray to contain the file argument - OK

  // create and attempt to populate a LSApplicationParameters instance - problematic

  // call LSOpenURLsWithRole - failure. Returned error code is -50

}`



The returned error code I usually get I understand to map to the message:
"Error in user parameter list".

As far as I can tell, Snow Leopard seems to have dropped support for a range of APIs that take a FSRef as an argument. It's not at all clear to me just where I stand with what's supported and what isn't.

So I should conclude Carbon is a dead duck for this activity? Or am I closer than I think?

Tx

Answer (score 0):

Having given up on Carbon's LSOpenApplication, I've implemented a solution which uses Rococoa to bridge Objective-C and Java. Not the the necessity of translating Cocoa composite method names eg openFile:withApplication to openFile_withApplication.

```
// Declare an interface which will call on a rococoa class:

public interface NSWorkspace extends NSObject
{

    public static final _Class CLASS = Rococoa.createClass("NSWorkspace", _Class.class);

    public interface _Class extends NSClass
    {
        // static method to get the workspace in
        NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace();
    }
    boolean openFile_withApplication(NSString fullPath, NSString appName);
}

// then we can call on it to do stuff

final NSWorkspace nsWorkspace = NSWorkspace.CLASS.sharedWorkspace();
boolean isRunning = nsWorkspace.openFile_withApplication(
    NSString.stringWithString(targetFilePathStr),
    NSString.stringWithString(executableApplicationPathStr));
```

I'm still using Carbon for a number of other LaunchApplication services.
java.net/projects/rococoa/ is its home, with some useful if minimal chatter on java.net/projects/rococoa/lists/users/archive